# React Native call setState multiple time make app crashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React component i have a button who update my score

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  state = {
    score: 0,
    isButtonClickable: true
  }

  onPress() {
    const {isButtonClickable, score} = this.state
    if (isButtonClickable) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isButtonClickable: true})
      }, 2000)
    }
    const newScore = isButtonClickable ? score + 1 : 0
    this.setState({isButtonClickable: false, score: newScore})
  }

  render() {
    <View>
      <View>{this.state.score}</View>
      <Button onPress={() => this.onPress()}</Button>
    </View>
  }
}
```

When the button is trigger, the user can't push on the button during 
2 seconds else the score is reset to 0

When he push on the button the score is increment with 1

On my Iphone and Android simulator, when i push multiple time on button the app crash and i don't know how to optimize my code to avoid crash

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Why have you used setTimeOut?

Try the code below

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  state = {
    score: 0,
    isButtonClickable: true
  }

  onPress() {
    const {isButtonClickable, score} = this.state
    if (isButtonClickable) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isButtonClickable: true})
      }, 2000)
    }
    const newScore = isButtonClickable ? score + 1 : 0
    this.setState({isButtonClickable: false, score: newScore})
  }

  render() {

    return(
    <View>
      <View>{this.state.score}</View>
      <Button onPress={() => this.onPress()} disabled={!this.state.isButtonClickable}>Click</Button>
    </View>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the user have a delay to push again on button, 2 seconds

Comment: It isn't required to clear setTimeout. Try the code above

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: Do you want to reset the score to 0 if clicked on disabled?

Answer (score 0):

In your timeout you never clear it, so this code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isButtonClickable: true})
      }, 2000)
```

will run all the time every 2 seconds, and then once you have clicked it 4 times -  you'll have 4 timeouts running setting the state.

Have a read here about timeouts:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

use:

```
 let myVar = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isButtonClickable: true})
      }, 2000);
```

To stop use:

```
 clearTimeout(myVar);
```

Comment: After your state has been set with the new isButtonClickable

Answer (score 0):

If you want your score to be 0 if user clicks on button before the `2s` delay, and also don't have problems with app crashing, you could have 2 different buttons. 1 for adding and changing the `isButtonClickable` state, and 1 for going back to 0.

```
render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <p>{this.state.score}</p>
    {this.state.isButtonClickable ? (
       <button onClick={() => this.onPress()}>aaaa</button>
    ):(
       <button onClick={() => this.makeZero()}>aaaa</button>
    )}

  </div>
)};
```

And your `makeZero` ( or how you want to call it ) should be placed inside the Class

```
 makeZero = () => {
   this.setState({ score: 0})
 }
```

See fiddle -> [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uotr7ph1/)

Comment: How to reset score to 0 if user click on disable button